# Send application email again to avoid being overlooked

Tags: internship, applications, email

I am a second-year master's student. All of my courses are in the evenings, and I am looking for a part-time internship or job for me to do before I attend classes in the evening.

There is an internship opportunity at a think tank that I think that I am well-qualified for, both in terms of research area and foreign language abilities. The deadline has not passed yet, and the application directions were to submit a CV, a cover letter, and a short writing sample via email.

I already submitted these materials via email, but is there a possibility of my application being *overlooked*? Should I *send my email again*, or would that look annoying?

Answer (score 7):

> Should I send my email again, or would that look annoying?

If you already followed all the directions you were given to submit your application, then sending that redundant email could indeed most likely be seen as annoying or unprofessional. To some degree, it can also make you look somewhat desperate, and that may be something you don't want to convey.

If they gave you those directions, then there is little chance your application got overlooked, as that seems to be the application process they expect.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is incredibly annoying when you are the hiring manager.

Most employers have a process they follow for hiring, and for things like internships this might well include having a deadline to submit applications by and not doing anything with applications until the deadline is reached, so that all the applicants can be fairly evaluated side-by-side (e.g. if we get 100 applications but only plan to interview 10 people, we want to try and ensure we're interviewing the 10 best applicants).

Some employers will evaluate applications as they're received and contact people they find interesting as soon as possible. This is also valid (though less so for prestigious internships perhaps) but again the dynamic is that you follow their application process and they contact you if they wish.

Submitting your application multiple times shows that you're unaware of the normal hiring process and does not reflect you in a favorable light.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach you can use.  The RPost registered e-mail service can indicate to you if your message has been received or opened.  You could sign up for RPost for free, and then re-send your e-mail through RPost.  Add "Revised:" to the beginning of the subject line.  You don't have to actually revise anything, unless you really need to; the point is to make the second message you send *trackable*.  Your intentions will be far less obvious to the sender, and you'll know, by way of RPost's back-end, if the e-mail is overlooked.

I don't work for (or earn money from) RPost.

Comment: If you add "Revised" without actually revising, you risk someone wasting time re-reading and comparing to see what has changed from the first version they read.